# Windows Azure Solr install extensions

Tags: azure, solr

I know it's possible to run Solr in Azure ([Solr in Azure](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/Azure/Getting_Started_Guide_Solr_Lucene.asp)), but what about install extensions? 
Any one achive that? Can anyone share the experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this.  You could use a VM Role and set it up before you upload it to Azure or you could manually deploy your project using the portal and include a startup script that configures it.  Keep in mind that you may need to update some ini files for the extension.

Comment: I'm trying to use the project Solr on Azure. If is "only" configure ini files I go try it!
Thanks!